# Convert animated WebP to GIF with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webp

So, I have already forked a working Chrome extension with support to save static WebP to JPG/PNG. But now I'm looking to implement support to save animated WebP to GIF in the extension.

Haven't found anything ATM when searching for a solution for it. Only to save JPG and other format to WebP!

Comment: Hi Tideman, what your code looks like right now?

Comment: Right now the code is like this: https://github.com/PontusTideman/Save-Image-as-Type/blob/master/background.js

It's a working extension that works fine for saving images to JPG, PNG and WebP. But not the other way around.

Comment: Find a C library that does this and compile it using emscripten to JS and/or WASM.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a webp2gif solution recently, and it resolved smoothly.
You can first understand WebAssembly, which is a technology that can run C, C ++ or other languages ​​in the browser.

So I found the imagemagick image processing library, and then I found the compiled wasm file on github. I have tested that it can smoothly convert webp animations to gifs. Although the conversion speed is a bit slow, he can work normally. In the end, I integrated it into my project and it worked well.

imagemagick WASM , Support jpg, png
gif, webp files  https://github.com/mk33mk333/wasm-im